# Return List of Objects from stored procedure return data C#

Tags: c#

I have a method that is calling a stored procedure and returning a list of objects. I am not sure how to add the result from the stored procedure to the list of objects. I tried to use model. Add but anyway I am using it I am getting error. I have identify the place I need help inside the code.

This is my code:

```
    public List<Models.Type> get_Type(string Type_Group)
    {
        string connectionName = getConnectionStr();
        List<Models.Type> model = null;

        string myConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ToString();
        SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(myConnection);

        using (DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("LA_Get_Type"))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(command, "Type_Group", DbType.String, Type_Group);

            var result = db.ExecuteReader(command);

            try
            {
                if (result.FieldCount == 0)
                    model = null;
                else
                {
                    while (result.Read())
                    {
                     model = new List<Models.Type>()
                        {

    //This is the place I don't know I tried   model.Add but not sure what 
     to have after. 
     This code is when I have returning just 1 object but I want to 
     return list of objects                           


                            typeID = Convert.ToInt32(result["typeID"].ToString()),
                            type_group = result["type_group"].ToString(),
                            type_value = result["type_value"].ToString(),
                            type_desc = result["type_desc"].ToString(),
                            type_sort = Convert.ToInt32(result["type_sort"].ToString())
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            result.Close();
            return model;
        }
    }
```

and this is my object:

```
  public class Type
  {

    public int typeID { get; set; }
    public string type_group { get; set; }
    public string type_value { get; set; }
    public string type_desc { get; set; }
    public int type_sort { get; set; }

  }
```

Comment: Hi Alma, could you please add the error detail?, Note: Move the list initializer outside of the while method if you are getting more than 1 result, otherwise you would be initializing an empty list for every record and it will return 1 record always

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx may be a useful example where the stored procedure returns multiple records.

Comment: @JBKing I am using kind of different way than this page you provide as I am using Enterprise Library.

Comment: @darkndream I am not sure how to write model.Add(......) what should I have after?

Comment: @Alma model.Add(-->individual item of the type of the model here<--);
for example `List<dog> dogs = new List<dog>;` then `dogs.Add(new dog(name: "Puppy"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
                while (result.Read())
                {
                 model = new List<Models.Type>()
                    {

//This is the place I don't know I tried   model.Add but not sure what 
 to have after. 
 This code is when I have returning just 1 object but I want to 
 return list of objects                           


                        typeID = Convert.ToInt32(result["typeID"].ToString()),
                        type_group = result["type_group"].ToString(),
                        type_value = result["type_value"].ToString(),
                        type_desc = result["type_desc"].ToString(),
                        type_sort = Convert.ToInt32(result["type_sort"].ToString())


                    };
                }
```

to something like this:

```
                model = new List<Models.Type>();
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    Models.Type aModel = new Model(){
                        typeID = Convert.ToInt32(result["typeID"].ToString()),
                        type_group = result["type_group"].ToString(),
                        type_value = result["type_value"].ToString(),
                        type_desc = result["type_desc"].ToString(),
                        type_sort = Convert.ToInt32(result["type_sort"].ToString())
                    };
                    model.Add(aModel);
                }
```

Note that I'm creating a new object for each result and then adding them one by one to the list.

Comment: Thank you so much that was exactly what I was looking for.